# Sort output of getValues() in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, google-apps-script

I try to sort an array of values in google script. I got the values with `.getRange().getValues()`. I want to sort them ascending, but don't know how. I already tried different solutions, but nothing helped. Have maybe someone an idea? Code looks like this at the moment:

Thanks in advance

```
var values = simsSheet.getRange("A1:NTP1").getValues();
   values.sort(function(a,b){
     return a - b;
   });
Logger.log(values);
```

Comment: Have you looked into what `a` and `b` are? `getValues` returns `Object[Object[]]`... (i.e., an array of arrays)

Comment: What are your values?

Comment: @AntonDementiev values don't matter yet - OP's comparator function is subtracting an array from an array.

Comment: Agreed, but they matter if he wants to compare strings ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to decide on which column you want to do the sorting and on what criteria. As mentioned in the comments, your data is an array of arrays so you have to examine data one level further.
The most common form of code used for that is as follows :

```
array.sort(function(x,y){  // tri libellé simplifié
    var xp = x[0]; // in this case on the first column
    var yp = y[0]; // same
    return xp < yp ? -1 : xp > yp ? 1 : 0;
  });
```

if you want to sort on numeric values for example or on just a part of the data then change the value of x[0] and y[0] to the type of data you want.
For example `xp = parseInt(x[0],10);` would sort on the integer value (without decimals) of the data... a lot of possible variations as you can imagine